# Django: Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

Tags: python, django

I'm a new face to Django so please be considerate to if ever my problem is something stupid. In this case I want to delete an item in my database, if I click on the button, the html will pass an id to `views.py`, then the funtion `Delete()` will delete this item. But whatever I tried it dosen't have any response.

Now I add  `action="{% url 'todolist:delete' todo.id %}"` in  `home.html`, but it met some error : `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']` , and I don't know how to solve it. So please give me some advice, I'll be really grateful.

My codes are as follows:

project/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('todolist.urls', namespace='todolist')),
]
```

todolist/urls.py:

```
app_name = "todolist"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Add, name = 'add'),
    path('', views.Delete, name = 'delete'),
]
```

home.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'todolist:delete' todo.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
  <tbody>
    {% for each in todo_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><div class="thing"><input type="checkbox" name="done" value="done"><label>{{each.todo}}</label></div></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="E"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" value="x"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def Delete(request, id):
    if 'delete' in request.POST:
        todo = Todo.objects.get(id=id)
        todo.delete()
        todo_list = Todo.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'todolist/home.html', {'todo_list': todo_list, 'todo': todo})
```

Comment: Why don't you use [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)?

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana Yes, obviously he can use DetailView. But, for now (begining) I don't think he should directly be using DeleteView as he has to understand the processes and their importance.

Answer (score 1):

Your url does not look good. If you look at this code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Add, name = 'add'),       
    path('', views.Delete, name = 'delete'),  <--- url path same as above 
]
```

But, the error is not coming from this. It is talking about arguments. So:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add', views.Add, name = 'add'),       
    path('del/<str:id>', views.Delete, name = 'delete'),   
]
```

Now, your `delete` path will be taking an argument from:

```
<form action="{% url 'todolist:delete' todo.id %}" method="post">
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path) you can see more about path.

Comment: I‘ve followed your advice, but the error still exists: `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['del/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$']`

Comment: Try: `<form action="{% url 'delete' todo.id %}" method="post">`

Comment: I've tried `<form action="{% url 'delete' todo.id %}" method="post">` but the error turned to `Reverse for 'delete' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`...So I had to change it to `'todolist:delete'`.

Comment: Are u sure your paths are not same.

Comment: Yes. I've changed them to `path('add/', views.add, name = 'add')` and `path('del/<int:id>/', views.delete, name = 'delete')` just like you do.

Comment: can you check if `todo.id` has some `id` or is it returning NULL value.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know how to check it. I can't get the right view because of the error, unless I change `action="{% url 'todolist:delete' todo.id %}"` to `action=""`. Now I add `<p>{{todo_id}}</p>` in `home.html` and `return render(request, 'todolist/home.html', {'todo_list': todo_list, 'todo_id': id})` in views.py. When I click the button the <p> tag didn't appear. Does it mean that the `id` is NULL?

Comment: Yes that is the  reason your url is not working. Try making sure that your `todo_id` actually contains data.

Comment: But why it doesn't contain any data? I don't know how to make it. I'm sorry I'm still a rookie on this. I've also tried `todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)` to derectly delete the first item in my funtion but it still didn't work. It seems that the problem isn't in here

Comment: `def delete(request):
    if 'delete' in request.POST:
        todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)
        todo.delete()
    todo_list = Todo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'todolist/home.html', {'todo_list': todo_list, 'todo_id': id})`

Comment: Or would you like to leave your gmail address thus I can send u my total codes?

Answer (score 0):

Django Templates Approach ( FormClass, TableClass )

(urls.py)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('label/<int:pk>/delete/',DeleteLabelView.as_view(),name='delete.label'),
]
```

(Views.py)

```
class **DeleteLabelView**(DeleteView):
    model = PageLabel
    template_name = '/delete_label.html'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('workspaces:label.list')
```

> **I have passed action.html as **template_name** file in **DeleteLabelView**, insted i need to pass template_name = '/delete_label.html'**

That's why I am getting this error.